# JHipster 4.14.5 - An error has occured site when running project

Tags: java, jhipster

I'v got problem. I need to make project with AngularJs, I need old JHipster (since 5 its no loonger support angularjs) and i got error site. Project is running without problems and giving me info that project is running at localhost... Iv got java 1.8, node 14.7.1, and do not know what to do... please help!

Comment: We can't help you with so few details about the error. Please **edit your question** with full error log and command you ran.

Comment: Just a lucky guess, but I could imagine the node/npm version is to new for the old angular.js. But to be honest, why not use angularx with newer jhipster version?